# What do we call $\mathfrak{M}$?

Tags: measure-theory, terminology

I am starting to learn some measure theory, and I was wondering if there is a name for $\mathfrak{M}$.

I have the definition:

> A collection $\mathfrak M$ of subsets of a set $X$ is said to be a $\sigma$-algebra in $X$ if $\mathfrak M$ has the following properties:
>   blahblah
>
> If $\mathfrak M$ is a $\sigma$-algebra in $X$, then $X$ is called a measurable space, and the members of $\mathfrak{M}$ are called the measurable sets in $X$.

---

Now in topology, we call $\tau$ a topology. What do we call $\mathfrak M$? A collection of measurable sets? Is that the shortest we can do? 'A collection of measure' or something like that?

Comment: To indicate that you are considering the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathfrak M$ as part of the measureable space $(X, \mathfrak M)$, you might call $\mathfrak M$ *the* $\sigma$-algebra of the measureable space $X$, or simply *the* $\sigma$-algebra of $X$. To call $\mathfrak M$ *a* collection of measureable sets is ambiguous, since a subset $A \subset \mathfrak M$ is also a collection of measureable sets.  But it would be fine to call $\mathfrak M$ *the* set of all measureable sets. I don't know of any shorter name for $\mathfrak M$.

Comment: Thanks @MPO. I was tempted to add a joke at the end calling it a 'measurology' but I expected downvotes for that.